# How to upload files using ajax in Codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a grid and in this list of data shown and every row has a edit action.

So when Edit button press a popup will open and in this i want to update data and upload a image regarding this selected row.

Data is successfully updated but image is not save in folder.

**In Code What I did :**

In ajax, i serialize all data when form submit but upload file post data is not showing so i am doing this -

```
var mts = $('#userfile').val();
    var formdata = $('form[name=data_popup]').serialize()+'&IMG_URI='+mts;
    console.log(formdata);
```

HTML Code:

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="data_popup">
 <input type="file" name="userfile">
</form>
```

Jquery Code :

```
function update_cat(){
    var mts = $('#userfile').val();
    var formdata = $('form[name=data_popup]').serialize()+'&IMG_URI='+mts;
    console.log(formdata);
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?=$this->config->base_url()?>admin_panel/update_data/',
            type: 'post',
            data: formdata
        }).done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
        });
    }
```

Codeigniter Model Code:

```
$this->load->library('upload');
            $config['upload_path'] = "./application/assets/images/logo";
            $config['allowed_types'] = "gif|jpg|png|jpeg";
            $config['file_name'] = date('dmYHis');
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');
            $data_upload_files = $this->upload->data();
            $image = $data_upload_files[file_name];
```

Comment: Form name `name="builder_popup"` not `data_popup`

Comment: Yes, I already did but nothing new happen

Comment: you can use `$("#formID").ajaxsubmit` instead of `$.ajax` it will post whole form at once it will require form.js file

Answer (score 0):

Use FormData for ajax upload

```
var formdata = new FormData($('form[name="data_popup"]')[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

`HTML`

`<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="data_popup">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile">
</form>`

```
JavaScript

function update_cat(){
    var formData = new FormData();

    var mts = $('#userfile').get(0).files[0];

    formData.append('userfile', mts);

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?=$this->config->base_url()?>admin_panel/update_data/',
            method: 'post',
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
}


PHP

<?php

$this->load->library('upload');

$config['upload_path'] = "./application/assets/images/logo";
$config['allowed_types'] = "gif|jpg|png|jpeg";
$config['file_name'] = date('dmYHis');

$this->upload->initialize($config);

$this->upload->do_upload('userfile');

$data_upload_files = $this->upload->data();
$image = $data_upload_files['file_name'];
```

Note: I didn't do much on the PHP part since I don't have a full understanding of what you want to do with the file.

Also ensure you call the javaScript function somehow.

Comment: console says files is undefien, var mts = $('#userfile').get(0).files[0];

Comment: Did you modify the HTML part? I added an ID named `userfile`.